# Include does not load related data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Any idea why this line

```
var guild = _context.Guilds.Include(x => x.Heroes).Single(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Will leave heroes null on the guild but if I do this first

```
var heroes = _context.Heroes.ToList();
var guild = _context.Guilds.Include(x => x.Heroes).Single(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Then heroes on the guild object has been included and now works fine?

DbContext

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Guild> Guilds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hero> Heroes { get; set; }
}

public class Hero : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string AvatarId { get; set; }
}

public class Guild : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get;  set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Hero> Heroes { get; set; }

    public void AddHeroes(IEnumerable<Hero> heroes)
    {
        foreach (var hero in heroes)
        {
            Heroes.Add(hero);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add both classes and how you configured them on the DbContext?

Comment: Nothing special about it

Comment: Where's the Foreing Key that links `Hero` to `Guild`? You need a `GuildId` in `Hero`

Comment: I dont think so as ef core seems to have figured that out with the migration script, also that would not explain how include works fine when calling all the heroes first

Comment: Tried adding anyway and still nothing

Comment: Please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) to enable SQL logging. We'll need to see what SQL is being generated and what's your database